# Merge two arrays if one of the values equals a key

Tags: php, php-5.3

Hello I have two arrays one $roles and the second $permission. What I would like to do is to merge those two arrays based on the key from roles if it's equal to the value from the second array. I'm not sure how to do it I tried with a foreach, but I got stuck on the checking the value and assigning the end result should be something similar to $rolePermissions.

```
// Roles indexed by ID
$roles = array(
    1 => 'Administrator',
    2 => 'Moderator',
    3 => 'Admin',
    4 => 'User',
    5 => 'SuperUser',
    6 => 'Accountant',
    7 => 'God'
);

// Permissions indexed by ID
$permissions = array(5) 
[
    0 => array(2) 
        [
            "PermissionName" => string(12) "Catalog-View"
            "RoleId"         => string(2) "22"
        ]
    1 => array(2) 
        [
            "PermissionName" => string(12) "Catalog-View"
            "RoleId"         => string(2) "23"
        ]
    2 => array(2) 
        [
            "PermissionName" => string(12) "Catalog-Edit"
            "RoleId"         => string(2) "22"
        ]
    3 => array(2) 
        [
            "PermissionName" => string(14) "Catalog-Delete"
            "RoleId"         => string(2) "22"
        ]
    4 => array(2) 
        [
            "PermissionName" => string(14) "Article-Delete"
            "RoleId"         => string(2) "22"
        ]
]

// Assign role IDs to permission IDs, array is indexed by role ID
$rolePermissions = array(
    1 => array(1),
    2 => array(1, 2),
    3 => array(1, 2, 3)
);
```

EDIT:
What i did so far but didn't manage getting the result.

```
foreach ($roles as $key => $value) {
    foreach($permissions as $row) {
        if($key == $row['RoleId'])
            $perm[$key][] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you found "foreach" then you're a good way there. If you got stuck, show some code, show an example of what you want and what you got, and tell us what you debugged.

Comment: I can not see any error in your foreach code. It may throw a warning about uninitialized variable, but still do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `$roles` you have role IDs of numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

in `$permissions` you have role IDs of numbers 22 or 23

of course it will never find a match